# How work short if in PHP when true section is empty?

Tags: php, syntax

I use short if in PHP, and when Use this example

```
$a = 100 ? 200 : 300;
```

`$a` equal **200**, but i don't know how below example work.

```
$a = 100 ?  : 300;
```

after this code `$a` equal **100**.
Why?

Comment: You've mistakenly set the value of `$a` to 100 instead of checking if it equals 100. `$a == 100 ? 200 : 300;`

Comment: If this is a common mistake of yours, try using more Yoda conditions: `100 == $a`. If you had mistyped that as `100 = $a ? 200 : 300` that would have shown an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression `expr1 ?: expr3` returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain so you can understand the differnece.

```
When you use one = it's assigning value, 
When you use == is checking if same value and 
When using === is checking value + type also.
```

So in your example `$a = 100 ? 200 : 300;` it is like this:

If $a can be set to 100 (which can) then True (so 200).

In your second example : `$a = 100 ?  : 300;`

Again you are assinging $a to 100, which is true, so it remains 100 as your true condition is empty.